# Spectral Graph Theory and Matroid Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory

I have just started grad school this year and I have been into Spectral Graph Theory for some time now. Recently I got introduced to Matroid Theory and although I know the field has been around for decades, it somehow feels "hot" lately.

I know that Matroid Theory is related to both Graph Theory and Linear Algebra. The question is though, is there a connection to Spectral Graph Theory? Has there been any work in trying to combine results of the two fields? Does anyone have the intuition that there is some common ground of potentially interesting and useful results?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: A quick search on google leads to http://www.math.uri.edu/~andrewk/Specpoly.pdf and
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/ReinerVictor/Reiner9.pdf. You may want to try your luck at mathoverflow as well.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will check them out! Although the main focus of my question is on at that level per se, I am interested in the implicit common basis these fields share and the theoretical implications that they could result to.